# How to get/set interpretation window scale

Tags: ocean

3D/2D windows have a Z-scale property.  Do intersection/interpretation windows have anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is "no". In 3D window Z-scale is realized via SoScale node, Interpretation/Intersection windows use other engine.

---

Update: There is no access to viewport's Z-scale for Interpretation/Intersection window. You can simulate pseudo changes via IntersectionWindow.Bounds, but it doesn't affect viewport's Z-scale. You can submit an official enhancement request via www.ocean.slb.com (Developer's pages) if you wish.

Comment: I don't think it's hard to understand what he's asking for: the ability to modify the exaggerated vertical scale of said windows.  If the intersection window had provided APIs for the viewport coordinates, at least the effect could be simulated, but no such luck.